# Should I use the plural or singular for "skill" as in "cooking skill"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

I want to compliment someone for her good cooking skills, but I'm not sure whether it is more grammatical to use the plural or singular form of "skill". For example, should I use:

> "Your cooking skills is great!"

OR

> "Your cooking skills are great!"

OR

> "Your cooking skill is great!"

Not sure which to use. Can someone explain the correct usage?

Comment: How about, "You are a culinary artist!"

Comment: I've edited this question a little to make it more about correct grammar, does this suffice for a re-open?

Comment: @LeoKing, it is obviously a question about grammatical usage. I doubt your edit will make any difference. The way this site works is like meta: people who don't like it will find all kinds of reasons to close it.

Comment: That doesn't seem consistent with my understanding of a meta, that sounds consistent with the definition of intransigence of stubbornness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle one, 'your skills are great' is correct because 'skills' is a plural form. 
Cooking is generally thought of in this way, even if your friend is only good at one aspect, like making cakes, etc.

Comment: It sounds a bit - no, a lot - unidiomatic. As would "Your cooking skill is great!" "You're a wonderful cook!" hits the mark. "Her cooking skills are / skill is legendary" sounds fine, in a less intimate register.